# How to to detect if an audio is too loud?

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm using [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) to streaming audio. Does anyone know how to detect if an audio is too loud? And how to balance it?

Comment: Define too loud.  Isn't that up to the user?  Some people want it loud.

Comment: Are you wanting to normalise the volume between multiple sound clips or what are you asking?

Comment: yeah it's normalizing the volume

Comment: loud in here is yelling sound, bomb exploding...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`AudioManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) for that purpose, and get the [volume index](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getStreamVolume(int))

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)GetSystemService(AudioService);
int currentVolume = am.GetStreamVolume(Stream.Music);
```

And check if it has greater `volume index` than your `limit Volume`

```
if(currentVolume > limitVolume){
  // Some action
}
```

Comment: you just get system volume using this way, but what i really want is detect if some audio have unexpected loud sound (eg. yelling sound, bomb exploding, ...)